# Unable to run client server application on remote computer c++

Tags: c++, server, tcp, client

In a typical client server app that takes a port number as an argument (server) and port number and IP (client) as arguments.
Assume cat is the server and dog is the client

Why would it be that when you run the server on cat and the client on dog it returns the error connecting to socket? However when the server is ran on dog and the client on cat it works as intended. ( Same exact port numbers and IP are used)
I have tried quite a few different ports
The following functions are just for example files

**For the server:** These are the functions I am using

```
int server_sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

int bindStatus= bind(server_sock, (struct sockaddr*) &servAddr,sizeof(servAddr));

listen(server_sock, 5);

socklen_t newSockAddrSize = sizeof(newSockAddr);

int accept_sock = accept(server_sock, (struct sockaddr *)&newSockAddr, &newSockAddrSize)

close(accept_sock);

close(server_sock);
```

**For the client:** These are the functions I am using

```
int client_sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

int status = connect(client_sock,(sockaddr*) &sendSockAddr, sizeof(sendSockAddr));

close(client_sock);
```

Comment: *"In a typical client server app that takes a port number as an argument (server) and port number and IP (client) as arguments."* -- aside from this being a sentence fragment, why is this relevant? Your demo code manages to sidestep the question of where this data comes from (which might be a good thiing if that is not part of the problem).

Comment: *"Same exact port numbers and IP are used"* -- why is this the correct thing to do?

Comment: @JaMiT  -- aside from this being a sentence fragment  (not entirely understanding what the point of this statement was)     --why is this the correct thing to do? (The ports have to be the same to allow the connection between client and server. My reason for pointing it out is that in one set up it works but does not work in the reverse way (where cat is the server and dog is the client) I did not mention the entire code as I did not feel that it applied to my problem. Thanks.)

Comment: *"(not entirely understanding what the point of this statement was)"* -- my point is that your opening "sentence" is not a complete sentence. This has a few notable negatives. 1) You might have accidentally left out part of what you intended to write. 2) Readers might misunderstand your intent when they try to interpret your fragment as a complete sentence. 3) Readers might decide to stop reading, down vote, and move on. (As mentioned in [ask], correct grammar helps make questions better received.)

Comment: *"The ports have to be the same to allow the connection between client and server."* -- OK, that answers half of what I asked. What about the other half: Why is it correct to use the same IP address for both computers?

Comment: @JaMiT what I meant was regardless of whether it is ran as a server on dog or on cat the results should be the same, right? However it is not i can run one as a server and not the other. So on cat i run `g++ server.cpp -o server` and then run `./server 9874` and then I switch to putty where I have remote computer dog open and so I proceed to run `g++ client.cpp -o client` and then run `./client * input ip address of cat* 9874` it does not connect and says error connecting to socket.    However, if you flip dog and cat in my last sentence it works as intended.